# How is relative positioning specified in Favicon links

Tags: html

For example `utexas.edu` prepend the path with a `/`

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/sites/default/files/webcentral_favicon_0.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

`columbia.edu` does not, it just starts with the folder name or path

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="sites/all/themes/base/columbia2/images/favicon-crown.png" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Both of these are relative, but I need a way to differentiate from absolute pahts.

How can I progrmatically tell when I'm working with a relative path or an absolute path?

Comment: How do you mean programatically? in JS?

Comment: Aren't both of them relative?

Comment: I mean I need to pull the favicon into my code and set the img.src...so I need to know where it is...I do know that these are both relative paths...but I need a way to differentiate them from absolute path...previously I used the '/' but this no longer works.

Comment: @WojekT There are different level of `absoluteness`. Usually people refer to a site relative URL as absolute since it's not relative to a specific page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

URLS can be formatted like the following

- Absolute:

  http://google.com, https://google.com
- Scheme relative:

  //google.com links use the same scheme that the page was loaded

  //en.wikipedia.org/apple-touch-icon.png
- Site absolute:

  /index.html
- Page relative:

  index.html, ../index.html, ./index.html

I don't really understand the question, but you seem confused about what a relative/absolute URL is.

If you need to convert a relative URL into an absolute, you can use http://code.google.com/p/js-uri/

Comment: I have not seen ./ or../ used for favicons have you?

Comment: Page relative with out a ../ or a ./ behaves the same as site absolute...either way when populating img.src....you have to prepedend the domain followed by the path.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist If you show us what code you are trying to produce, we could help you more

Comment: I'm just parsing favicon paths to populate img.src...that's all...just getting started...you have provided excellent info...thanks.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist so you have a bot that looks for favicons and you need to convert the (maybe relative) URL on those crawled pages to a fully absolute URL so you can refer to it from other pages?

Comment: right....not so much a bot as a one line regex which will find the path...all in test phase

Comment: Wikipedia.org uses the // notation...or Scheme relative...I just removed the // and that works

Answer (score 3):

If the first character in the href value starts with `/` then it's relative to the root of the domain. If it starts with `.` then same directory.. `..` is a directory above and these can stack. If it doesnt start with those and not `//` or a full URL, then it's **relative**. And actually, `.` and `..` are relative too.

Be aware that it can also start with `//` or `https?` and in that case it would be absolute.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are doing and how it 'breaks this'? Show us code.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: That's not a relative path. That's an absolute path, just relative to the current document root (the website).

Comment: From the HTML: sites/all/themes/base/columbia2/images/favicon-crown.png

Comment: however the path is relative: columbia.edu/sites/all/themes/base/columbia2/images/favicon-crown.png, is the actual path.

Comment: I've been doing testing and this is the first site in about 20 that breaks this rule

Comment: Ok, why can't you work with it because of the missing `/`? If you are downloading it just prefix the domain to it.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist You make no sense, yes it's using as relative URL, but what's the problem it's causing you?

Comment: I need a way to identify it as relative..programatically.

Comment: If it doesn't start with a slash it's relative! `sites/all/themes/base/columbia2/images/favicon-crown.png` is relative to the home page `columbia.edu` so it's the exact same thing as `columbia.edu/sites/all/themes/base/columbia2/images/favicon-crown.png`

Comment: @meder Starting with `//`  is a scheme relative URL. That's the reason for my comment under the answer saying that there are different levels of absoluteness

Comment: I'm aware of that but it's just hard to categorize everything.

Comment: @meder - Just going to use check for absolute paths in my .js...as this is simpler...should just be a http:// or https:// ....so I can run a regex on http only...if I find it copy in the absolute path to my code.

Comment: 19 / 20 sites use a preceding slash for relative paths. 1 site does not use a preceding slash for a relative paths.  Hopefully absolute designations are more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check for the leading slash:

```
var link = $('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').attr('href');
var start = link.charAt(0); // Returns the leading slash (or not...)
if(start=='/'){
   return 'absolute';
}else{
   return 'relative';
}
```

Comment: Columbia.edu uses relative paths with out a preceeding /

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Relative paths do not start with a slash!

Answer (score 1):

If your "sites" directory is in the root directory of your site then both are equivalent. By the way, are you using Drupal? Drupal allows you to upload the favicon and the path is taken care of by it.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the first version of your question. Looks like you are trying to pull the favicon from other sites. You can check for absolute paths by checking for "http" and for relative paths, as long as you are taking the favicon URL from the homepage, the path with the site URL added infront should be fine.

Comment: I'm going to change my approach and check for absolute wrather than relative.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just look for an 'http' at the beginning of the URL? Even if you're connecting securely, if it's a full URL it should start with http.

Comment: They should all be http: or https: I believe.